# displaying particular data from entire json using laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have an issue in printing the data from the below json in laravel. Find below the json data and help me with this.

```
DarthSoup\Cart\Item Object ( [rowId] => 76cc22e6f533b8ef3d08e6eca0f110b4 [id] => 61XJrpB7CgiYSRCX6hR78wCEABhjLI7jNLzPyDrkYA3LyIVisz [name] => linux [quantity] => 1 [price] => 109 [options] => DarthSoup\Cart\CartItemOptions Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [package] => Super Lite ) ) [subItems] => DarthSoup\Cart\SubItemCollection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( ) ) [created_at:protected] => Carbon\Carbon Object ( [date] => 2018-06-22 05:41:18.674548 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => UTC ) [updated_at:protected] => Carbon\Carbon Object ( [date] => 2018-06-22 05:41:18.674574 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => UTC ) [associatedModel:protected] => [taxRate:protected] => 19 ) 1
```

From the above json how to display the "price=>109" and "package=>super Lite"...
I'm getting an error as "Cannot use object of type DarthSoup\Cart\Item as array"

Find below the controller Code:

```
public function addCart(Request $request)
{

$name = $request->input();
$hosting=$name['hosting'];
$package=$name['package'];
$price=$name['price'];
$response=Cart::add(['id'=>str_random(50) ,'name' => $hosting, 'quantity' => 1, 'price' => $price, 'options' => ['package' => $package]]);
//dd($response);
return Cart::content();
return view('main.cart',Cart::content());

}
```

Blade file is given below:

```
@foreach($response->options as $option){

    {{$option['name']}}
}

@endforeach
```

In my output I need to display the value of price,name and package...please help me to solve this error...

Comment: It is an object, don't use it as an array.

Comment: Can you help me how to declare this using foreach loop in laravel

Answer (score 0):

First this is not json, it is php `object`

if your variable name is `$item` then you can try this

```
$item->rowId;
$item->id;
$item->name;
$item->price;

foreach($item->options as $option){

   echo $option->package;

}
```

Comment: My controller code is given below
 `public function addCart(Request $request)
{

    $name = $request->input();
    $hosting=$name['hosting'];
    $package=$name['package'];
    $price=$name['price'];
    $response=Cart::add(['id'=>str_random(50) ,'name' => $hosting, 'quantity' => 1, 'price' => $price, 'options' => ['package' => $package]]);
    //dd($response);
    return Cart::content();
    return view('main.cart',Cart::content());

}`   Still I face the same error. can you help me with this...

Comment: @sharmila better you update your question with controller code

Comment: do you want to create record and return the created object ?